Allow custom TextInput wrapper to support UI testing `performTextInput`
I have this wrapper MyInput over compose's builtin TextField that does a series of UI operations and declares a style globally for all my inputs in the app.
I put all my components in a ui module and then I consume it from my different screens.
The problem is when I try to do UI testing and execute performTextInput("my@email.com") like so:
composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("enter_email_field")
                .assertIsDisplayed()
                .performTextInput("my@email.com")

and I get the following result:
java.lang.AssertionError: Failed to perform text input.
Failed to assert the following: (SetText is defined)
Semantics of the node:
Node #20 at (l=84.0, t=1500.0, r=1356.0, b=1699.0)px, Tag: 'enter_email_field'
Has 1 child, 10 siblings
Selector used: (TestTag = 'enter_email_field')

Would it be possible to have my custom MyInput support these semantics? I tried reading the source for TextField but I fail to see where this is declared?
if i declare the semantics for setText myself i am asked for requestFocus and then insertTextAtCursor? Id like to just inherit these from the inner BasicTextField

If your custom TextInput wrapper has TextField as a child of some other composable you should first get the child TextField and then perform text input on it.
composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("enter_email_field")
            .onChildren()
            .filterToOne(hasSetTextAction())
            .performTextInput("my@email.com")


You can create a helper function to avoid repetition.
fun SemanticsNodeInteraction.editTextNode() = onChildren().filterToOne(hasSetTextAction())

Previous Answer
If you want your custom text field to support performTextInput; make sure you are supplying the test tag on the inner TextField's Modifier.
This will work
@Composable
fun MyTextField(
    modifier: Modifier,
    testTag: String,
) {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("Initial") }
    Box(modifier) {
        TextField(text, { text = it }, Modifier.testTag(testTag))
    }
}

This won't
@Composable
fun MyTextField(
    modifier: Modifier,
    testTag: String,
) {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("Initial") }
    Box(modifier.testTag(testTag)) {
        TextField(text, { text = it }, Modifier)
    }
}


This would probably work but now the testTag is more explicit and polluting the code even more than with a modifier, isnt there a cleaner way?

testTag being used as a parameter was just for the example. You can add a second inputModifier param (although that could look uglier). Can you provide the code for your custom TextInput component for better clarity?

I've updated the answer which requires changing tests instead of source code.

I like your second approach. Thanks!
